# Load Unknown Number of Charts with Django Chartit

Tags: javascript, django, charts, highcharts

I have a script that generates multiple charts that are passed to the `datachart` variable in my chart.html.  I'd like to have each chart in it's own `<div>`.  It is easy enough to iterate through `datachart` and create the amount of `<div>` required, but the problem I'm facing is that the number of charts in `datachart` varies.  In the example below there are 12 charts generated and I have to manually pass `datachart|loadchart:"p1,p2,..."`.

Is there a way to iterate though the charts or a way to construct the `datachart|loadchart:"p1,p2,..."` dynamically based on the length of the `datachart` array?

**Snippet from chart.html Template**

```
<head>
    <!-- code to include the highcharts and jQuery libraries goes here -->
    <!-- load_charts filter takes a comma-separated list of id's where -->
    <!-- the charts need to be rendered to                             -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    {% load chartit %}
    {{ datachart|load_charts:"p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10,p11,p12" }}

</head>

<center>
    {% for c in datachart %}
      <div id='p{{forloop.counter}}' style="height: 40%; width: 80%">  </div>
    {% endfor %}
</center>
```

**views.py**

`views.py` appends to `charts` variable. `charts` ends up containing chartit objects, `[<chartit.charts.Chart object at 0x000001B3ECA44F60>, <chartit.charts.Chart object at 0x000001B3ECA6F0F0>,...]`

```
def getSurfData(request,pk, project_id, house_id, stage_id):
    client = Client.objects.get(pk=pk)
    project = Project.objects.filter(clients=client, pk=project_id).get()
    house = house.objects.filter(project=project, pk=house_id).get()

    stages = Stage.objects.get(house=house, pk=stage_id)

    pprop_type = PerfProperty.objects.filter(perf__in = stages.perf_set.all()).values('prop_type').distinct()

    for p in pprop_type:
        seriesOpt = []
        chartOpt = []
        for pNum in stages.perf_set.all():
            exp = PerfProperty.objects.filter(perf=pNum, prop_type=p['prop_type']).values('perf__perf_number','prop_type','time','value')
            options = {'options': {
                        'source':  exp,
                            },
                        'terms': [{'pt':'prop_type','t{}'.format(pNum):'time','Number {}'.format(pNum):'value'}]

                        }

            seriesOpt.append(options)

            options = {'options': {
                          'type': 'line',
                          },
                        'terms': {'t{}'.format(pNum): ['Number {}'.format(pNum)]}}
            chartOpt.append(options)

            dp = DataPool (series = seriesOpt)

            cht = Chart(
                    datasource = dp,
                    series_options = chartOpt,

                    chart_options =
                      {'title': {
                           'text': "{}".format(p['prop_type'])
                               },
                       'xAxis': {
#                            'categories':{'t{}'.format(pNum)},
                            'crosshair':'true',
                            'labels': {
                                'format': '{value}'
                        },
                            'title': {
                               'text':'Time'},
                            },
                        'yAxis':{
                            'title': {
                                'text': "Value"}

                                },
                        'chart': {
                            'zoomType': 'x',
                                },

                            })
        charts.append(cht)

#   
    return render(request,'reporter/chart.html',{'datachart': charts, 'client': client, 'projects': project, 'house': house, 'stage':stages})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I've come up with.  I tried looping through the `datachart`, but I believe chartit always names the js varialbe the same thing and the only chart that showing was the last one.  To overcome this, I made a custom tag that generates a string of all the div id's that is then passed to `load_charts`.

The custom tag `createDivId` is in:

**appname/templatetags/appname_extras.py**

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def createDivId(prefix, length):
    for n in range(len(length)):
        if n ==0:
            tmp = str(prefix)+str(n+1)
        else:
            tmp = str(tmp)+","+str(prefix)+str(n+1)
    print(tmp)
    return str(tmp)
```

**charts.html**

```
<head>
    <!-- code to include the highcharts and jQuery libraries goes here -->
    <!-- load_charts filter takes a comma-separated list of id's where -->
    <!-- the charts need to be rendered to                             -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    {% with divID="p"|createDivId:datachart %}
      {% load chartit %}
      {{ datachart|load_charts:divID}}
    {% endwith %}
</head>

<center>
    {% for c in datachart %}
        <div id='p{{forloop.counter}}' style="height: 40%; width: 80%"></div>
    {% endfor %}

</center>
```